# What is the preferred way to get entity_type_id in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, object-manager

When looking around the M2 source trying to figure out how to get the `entity_type_id` I see a lot of this :

```
$this->_entityTypeId = $this->_objectManager->create(
        'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity'
    )->setType(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY
    )->getTypeId();
```

However, I thought never invoking the ObjectManager directly was the new mantra in M2. Is this the best way to get the `entity_type_id`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Dependency Injection instead of the Object Manager:

```
private $eavConfig;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig
) {
    $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
}

public function myFunction()
{
    $entityTypeId = $this->eavConfig->getEntityType(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY)->getEntityTypeId();
}
```